# JSoup Select Problems

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm having trouble selecting links in my html. Here's the html I have:

```
<div class=first>
    <a href=www.test1.com>test1</a>

    <div class=nope>
        <a href=www.test2.com>test2</a>
        <a href=www.test3.com>test3</a>
        <a href=www.test4.com>test4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is pull the URLs:

www.test2.com

www.test3.com

www.test4.com

I have tried a lot of diferent .select and .not combinations but I just can't figure it out. Can anyone point out what it is I'm doing wrong?

```
String url = "<div class=first><a href=www.test1.com>test1</a>One<div class=nope><a href=www.test2.com>test2</a>Two</div></div><div class=second><a href=www.test3.com>test3</a></div>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url);
Elements divs = doc.select("div a[href]").not(".first.nope a[href]"); 
System.out.println(divs);
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your code?

Comment: I was testing it out with this snippet here

``String url = "<div class=first><a href=www.test1.com>test1</a>One<div class=nope><a href=www.test2.com>test2</a>Two</div></div><div class=second><a href=www.test3.com>test3</a></div>";

       Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url);

       Elements divs = doc.select("div a[href]").not(".first.nope a[href]");

       System.out.println(divs);``

Comment: @Peck3277: Please don't post code in comments since as you can see, the code is impossible to read. Better to edit your original post and then post a comment stating that you've posted an edit.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sorry about that, will do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("your html code/url ");
Elements links = doc.select("div.nope a").first();
for (Element link : links) {
System.out.println(link.attr("href"));
```

Comment: remove the .first(); in second line as it only returns one element.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it a little different:

```
  Elements elements = doc.select("div.nope").select("a[href]");

  for (Element element : elements) {
     System.out.println(element.attr("href"));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Elements data=doc.getElementsByClass("nope")

for(Element d:data)
{
    String yourData= d.tagName("href").toString();
}
```